# Chance to draw ball with 1 try is smaller than the chance with 2 tries

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say I have box of 100 balls. 2 are black and 98 white.
Chance to draw 1 black is $2/100=\frac{2\choose1}{{100}\choose{1}}$

Now whats the chance to draw at least 1 black without return with 2 tries? This must be a bigger chance right?

I know I don't have to use combinatorics, but its just for practice:

$\frac{2\choose1}{{100}\choose{2}}$ which is way smaller. What's my mistake here?

Comment: Do you mean *exactly* one or *at least* one?  If you meant *exactly* one, then there are $\binom 21\times \binom {98}1$ ways to choose an unordered mix-colored pair.

Comment: As a general remark:  if you know another method for solving the problem, I suggest doing it.  That way, you'll have something to tie out the combinatoric answer to.

Comment: @lulu I meant at least one, I edited. In the other case your solution says I had to make sure im adding the options for the second draw too (98) and that increases the chance. How to calculate it when its atleast one?

Comment: For at least $1$ (i.e. $1$ or $2$) it is $\dfrac{{2\choose 1}{98\choose 1}+{2\choose 2}{98\choose 0} }{{100\choose 2}}$

Comment: In this case, the difference between exactly one and at least one isn't hard...it's just the probability of getting both black balls. Alternatively, the complement of "at least" one black ball is "two white balls", which you can do by the same methods you have been using.